# Recursion pattern to find root items

Tags: swift, recursion, computer-science

I'm trying to figure out a way to find root items and their correlation.

In my case I have a list of "craftable Items" for a game.

For example:

- woodLog
- woodPlank
- woodWall

---

All these items have so called `parents` & `children`.
These are simple arrays of tuples that hold an `itemID` (which I can cast to an actual `Item` Object and an `amount` value.

For example:

```
typealias ParentTuple = (id: Int, amount: Float)
typealias ChildrenTuple = (id: Int, amount: Float)

var woodLog = Item(id: 1,
                   name: "Wood Log",
                   parents: [],
                   children: [ChildrenTuple(id: 2, amount: 2)]
                   )

var woodPlank = Item(id: 2,
                     name: "Wood Plank",
                     parents: [ParentTuple(id: 1, amount: 0.5)],
                     children: [ChildrenTuple(id: 3, amount: 4)]
                     )

var woodStick = Item(id: 3,
                     name: "Wood Stick",
                     parents: [ParentTuple(id: 2, amount: 0.25)],
                     children: []
                     )
```

As you can see a Wood Log can create 2 Wood Planks, while you need 0.5 Wood Logs to create 1 Wood Plank. (later I will ceil every value to the next full integer of course).

So following this logic from 1 Wood Log you should be able to craft 8 Wood Sticks.

- 1x Wood Log ->
- 2x Wood Plank ->
- 8x Wood Stick

Now what I need to know is how many Wood Logs would I need If I want to example craft 32 Wood Sticks?

I managed to recursively return a list of all `rootItems` (items that do not have any `parents`) of an item like so:

```
func rootItems() -> [ParentTuple] {
    guard self.isCraftable else { return [ParentTuple(self.id, amount: 1)] }

    var rootItems = [ParentTuple]()

    for (_, parentTuple) in self.parentIDs.enumerated() {
        guard let parentItem = Item.item(forID: parentTuple.id) else {
            assertionFailure()
            return [ParentTuple(self.id, amount: 1)]
        }
        if parentItem.isRootItem {
            rootItems.append(ParentTuple(id: parentTuple.id, amount: parentTuple.amount))
        } else {
            rootItems.append(contentsOf: parentItem.rootItems())
        }
    }

    return rootItems
}
```

This works great. I'm just stuck on how I would get the `amount` to work.
In theory for every recursive call I'd just have to multiply the current `parentTuple.amount` with the next one (in our example: 0.25 * 0.5 = 0.125 --> 1/8 Wood Log for 1 Wood Branch)

Is my model maybe not suited for that task, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this a little differently. Here's pseudoCode to illustrate

```
class Item {
    id : int?
    name : String?
    tier : Int?
    material : String?
}
```

Then when you define the `WoodLog`, `WoodPlank`, and `WoodStick` you can assign the `ID`, `tier`, and `material` then you can handle the calculations from the `tier` level. Adding `material` will also allow you to have more items of the same `material` and `tier` with minimal work and easily compare with other items to make sure you can dismantle or create with them.

```
func calcDismantleEfficiency(_ itemToMake: Item, _ itemToDismantle: Item) -> Int? {
    // array to get result based on tiers
    // the indices of tierArray are the itemToDismantle.tier
    // the subindices are the itemToMake.tier
    let tierArray = [[0,1,2,8,32...],
                     [0,0,1,4,16]...]
    if itemToDismantle.material == itemToMake.material {
         return tierArray[itemToDismantle.tier][itemToMake.tier] as! Int
    } else { return nil }

}
```

So if you call `calcDismantleEfficiency(WoodStick,WoodLog)` it will return 8.

```
func calculateCost(_ itemToMake: Item, _ itemToDismantle: Item, _ countToMake: Int ) -> Int? {
    if let efficiency = calcDismantleEfficiency(iteToMake, itemToDismantle) {
        if countToMake % efficiency == 0 {
            return countToMake / efficiency
        } else { return (countToMake / efficiency) + 1
    } else { return nil }
}
```

So if you cal `calculateCost(WoodStick, WoodLog, 64)` it should return 8

I didn't compile or test any of this by the way. this is all pseudocode

EDIT: Answering question in comments about multiple material items.

```
class Item: NSObject {
    var name : String?
    var id : Int?
    var tier : Int?
    var material : String?

    init(_ name : String?,_ id : Int?,_ tier : Int?,_ material : String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.tier = tier
        self.material = material
    }

}

class Equipment : Item {
    var components : [[Item : Int]]?

    override init(_ name : String?,_ id : Int?,_ tier : Int?,_ material : String?) {
        super.init(name, id, tier, material)
    }

    init(_ name : String?,_ id : Int?,_ tier : Int?,_ material : String?,_ components : [[Item : Int]]?) {
        super.init(name, id, tier, material)
        self.components = components
    }
}
```

> Basic example of how to proceed

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let item = Item(nil, nil, nil , "wood")
        let item2 = Item(nil,nil,nil,"metal")
        let equipment = Equipment(nil, nil, nil, nil, [[item : 1],[item2 : 5]])

        checkType(object: item2)
        checkType(object: equipment)
    }


    func checkType(object: NSObject) {
        if let obj = object as? Equipment {
            print("Equipment")
            // do work here
        } else if let obj = object as? Item {
            print("Item")
            // do work here
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks pretty good to me. But won’t this restrict me from having different amounts in the tiers? For example if I have other items that instead of 4 child items craft 8 and those craft only 1 instead of 4 will something like this still be possible?

Comment: You could create a preset `tier` object for each material and set what values are where. Or you can create one array and make it more basic. Your call.

Comment: For example `TierArray.wood = [[0,1,2,8,32,128],[0,0,1,4,16,64]...]` and `TierArray.metal` could equal something else entirely.

Comment: Now how would I go about if there are items that require meta & wood?

Comment: 'components’ takes an array of dictionaries where the key is the item it’s made of and the value is the amount of items required to make it.

Comment: Thank you again for your effort. I looked into your solution, but found that it'd be unfeasible to have those maps (tier arrays) for a larger database where items cross over different tiers. I managed to get it working recursively